# Logo not showing on tablet

Tags: android

I have an app and the logo shows on my Samsung Galaxy 4 but not on a ASUS Tablet. i've tried using  and everything

How can I fix this?

Here's the Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.xxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<compatible-screens>
    <!--no small size screens -->


    <!--all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

</compatible-screens>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:logo="@drawable/logons"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
```

So I have no idea why tho logo is showing on my phone but not on the tablets, it was like this before I added the compatible screens too.

Strings.xml

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>

        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>


    </style>
```

Comment: To clarify: is the logo not showing up in the launcher?  Also, why are you using the `compatible-screens` element?  Do you have a requirement to only support specific screen sizes?

Comment: Also, what API level is your ASUS tablet running on?

Comment: it's not showing up in the Action Bar on the tablet, but it is on the phone. And no, but i thought I'd give it a try, it didn't really change anything though. I added it after I learned that the logo wasn't showing on the tablet. The API level that the tablet is running on is 4.2.1

Comment: Gotcha.  So you probably want to remove that `compatible-screens` element, as the docs suggest that you don't use it.  Next question: is the icon showing up in the Action Bar? Or is nothing showing up?  Also, I know you mentioned you put a logo in the drawable folder for every size, do you have a copy of the logo in just the `/res/drawable/` folder as a fallback?

Comment: On the tablet, nothing is showing up on the action bar. I programmatically remove the up button and the icon so that makes sense. And no I don't have a res/drawable/ folder so I'll create that

Comment: Wait, I'm confused now.  If you programmatically remove the up button (which would be the logo in this case, correct?) where are you expecting it to be shown?  Also, how are you removing it? By setting `displayOptions`?

Comment: I thought the up button was the arrow that looks like a back button? That's what I removed. And see the xml that I added, that's how I'm defining the action bar.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51028/discussion-between-jonathan-and-user3140562)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `ic_launcher` in every drawable folders with the right size.
After that the logo gonna show itself.

For Samsung Galaxy S4 you have to put logo in `drawable-xxhdpi` folder.

Comment: It does show up on my s4 but not on the tablet. And all the images are already in every drawable folder.

Comment: what do you need logo for ?